# Jumping to the data segment

Tags: c, macos, assembly, dep

I am testing an assembler I am writing which generates X86 instructions. I would like to do something like this to test whether the instructions work or not.

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned char code[2] = {0xc9, 0xc3};

int main() {
  void (*foo)();
  foo = &code;
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

However it seems that OS X is preventing this due to DEP. Is there a way to either (a) disable DEP for this program or (b) enter the bytes in another format such that I can jump to them.

Comment: On Linux you'd use `mprotect(2)` to enable PROT_EXEC. It seem like that's also the way to go on [OSX](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man2/mprotect.2.html), but I'm not an expert.

Comment: For information, there are several libraries which might be useful for you. GNU lightning, libjit, http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/

Comment: Like @user786653 said, `mprotect` might be able to work, but remember to read the manual page if you change platform as for some the page needs to be allocated using `mmap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to test, try this instead, it's *magic*...

```
const unsigned char code[2] = {0xc9, 0xc3};
^^^^^
```

The `const` keyword causes the compiler to place it in the `const` section (warning! this is an implementation detail!), which is in the same segment as the `text` section.  The entire segment should be executable.  It is probably more portable to do it this way:

```
__attribute__((section("text"))
const unsigned char code[2] = {0xc9, 0xc3};
```

And you can always do it in an assembly file,

```
    .text
    .globl code
code:
    .byte 0xc9
    .byte 0xc3
```

**However:** If you want to change the code at runtime, you need to use `mprotect`.  By default, there are no mappings in memory with both write and execute permissions.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char *p = malloc(4);
    int r;
    // This is x86_64 code
    p[0] = 0x8d;
    p[1] = 0x47;
    p[2] = 0x01;
    p[3] = 0xc3;
    // This is hackish, and in production you should do better.
    // Casting 4095 to uintptr_t is actually necessary on 64-bit.
    r = mprotect((void *) ((uintptr_t) p & ~(uintptr_t) 4095), 4096,
                 PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
    if (r)
        err(1, "mprotect");
    // f(x) = x + 1
    int (*f)(int) = (int (*)(int)) p;
    return f(1);
}
```

The `mprotect` specification states that its behavior is undefined if the memory was not originally mapped with `mmap`, but you're testing, not shipping, so just know that it works just fine on OS X because the OS X `malloc` uses `mmap` behind the scenes (exclusively, I think).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your DEP on OSX, but another thing you could do would be to malloc() the memory you write the code to and then jump into this malloc'ed area. At least on Linux this memory would not be exec-protected (and in fact that's how a JIT usually does the trick).

Comment: No, memory returned by malloc is not executable on most Linux systems.

Comment: Does your processor support the NX bit (`grep /proc/cpuinfo nx`)?  The last time it worked for me was on a system without NX.